# Can you be a professional athlete without the use of steroids/AAS, SARMs, peptides/GH, etc.?

Tags: sports

Just as the title states. Is it possible for anyone to have the physical capacity to be a professional-level athlete without ever taking any steroids/AAS/testosterone, growth hormones/peptides, SARMs, or any other enhancement drugs like such? Or in other words, can one be 100% natural and be capable of performing well enough to play in professional sports teams, whether high or low level?

I ask because people point fingers and make blanket statements like, "99% of pro athletes are on drugs" and etc. If that's true, is it because it's impossible to be a pro athlete without them, or it's just easier to be a pro athlete with them? I'd like the reality here. I know it's a broad question, but still.....

I really ask because I have a smaller brother who wants to be an NHL player. People have told him that all of those guys use drugs, so he'll have to if he wants any chance at succeeding.

Comment: What do you consider a professional athlete? I know a number of people who are drug free and make a living through their sport, technically they're professional athletes as their sport is their profession.

Comment: Anyone who plays an organized sport before spectators for money. Examples include NHL, NBA, NFL, AFL, ABA, AHL, etc. Also, could really be anything from a dart thrower to a bowler as well, assuming they're making money too.

Comment: It is fair to assume, most of the olympians are free from illegal drugs. That is the best a human specimen can get without chemicals.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is NO, not all professional athletes are on drugs.

Some of them are, some aren't. The ratio of on drugs to not on drugs athletes is frankly a mystery.

We have testing organizations either within or outside of the professional organizations, etc, that specifically look for athletes they think are on drugs. And "randomly" test them, I say random because that's what they call it but it is almost always based on what the organization thinks the test will show, and is done with little to no warning.

If all pro athletes were on drugs the percentage of positives we get back would be much higher than it is. But to say that all or none of them are on drugs would be naive.

Finally, for your little brother, don't worry about the drug thing yet. 95-97% of the things that will make you a professional athlete (on drugs or not) consist of forms of Training, Nutrition, Recovery, and Genetics. You need to have all 4 of these on point before doing drugs will make the 3% difference between making it to the pros or not. Most people who do drugs in sports still suck, because they don't have the previous 4 things before doing the drugs.

Worry about being good before you worry about being legendary. Chances are you don't have the genetics to be a pro athlete but if you do, worry about Nutrition, Training, and Recovery before Drugs is even on your radar.

Comment: The testing barely keeps up with the blood doping, and for something like EPO you can basically dope enough to effectively argue that it was from being at high altitude. I'm not saying testing is ineffective, but it's not nearly as clear as "if you have x in you, you're doping, case closed." The doping market has been wise to this stuff for decades.

Comment: +1 for "Worry about being good before you worry about being legendary."

Comment: @EricKaufman - "blood doping" generally refers to a specific type of doping used in the late 80's, early 90's. And unfortunately, testing really does only catch the careless and stupid 90% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Every high level cyclist I knew when I raced was on some form of banned or quasi-banned substance, at the time (mid 90's) primarily [EPO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_doping#Erythropoietin). We heard in the old days that guys would take a pint of blood out of themselves during the fall and pop it into the freezer. Thaw and re-inject during the spring.

When you have that much of your career and life on the line (skipped college, no real alternatives, whole identity is your sport, etc) it's really hard to say "no" to something that lots of other people are doing with no adverse side effects.

I don't think anyone has enough knowledge to speak across all professional sports, and you can split hairs and talk about things like creatine which was banned, then it wasn't, and is now sort-of-not-really banned by some agencies.

For some sports, like snowboarding, I can't really see much advantage to performance enhancing drugs because it's really just about technique and practice. In cycling EPO was popular because you could train with it during the spring to push really hard and then by the summer racing system (when you got tested) it was out of your system.

And some folks, especially that live at high altitude, EPO levels are naturally higher anyway as [this 2007 study notes](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17955945).

> Short or prolonged residency at HA is associated with increased
>   secretion of EPO. The EPO response to hypoxia is not significantly
>   altered in AMS but is markedly enhanced in HAPE, which may be due to
>   exaggerated hypoxemia in these patients.

So back to splitting hairs, if you live at 8,000 feet and I live at sea level and I take EPO to get to the level that you have from being up there, how "unfair" is that?

The more you get into blood doping and performance enhancing drugs the grayer it gets. In general though I stayed out of it, and ultimately pulled out of high level cycling, because I didn't want to make a chemistry lab out of my blood stream. But it's a choice every athlete has to make for themselves. At minimum, I would work with a doctor you (or your brother, in this case) trusts. Tell them what you're doing, have blood tests done, and have a physician watching over you as you try to outsmart the human body.

Comment: Snowboarding - Muscular strength and endurance, both of which can be enhanced by PED's. And the notion of "fair" has always been extremely murky. Is it "fair" that someone that really likes basketball is only 5'6"? I'm the same as you. I lost out on a cross country scholarship because I wouldn't use the PED of the time. I moved on rather than take that path, but it was a very hard decision.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the answer short, from my opinion and experience: YES, but...

Yes - if you only want to be in that league or to earn money.

NO - if you want to be in the top of those leagues or Elite level competitor.

We are all genetically limited to a certain degree, and the top genetically gifted athletes still take some performance enhancements to set them appart from the other genetically gifted athlete.

Simply compare oldtime strongman like Louis Cyr against someone like Bill Kazmeier and you will easily understand.
How many of those Kazmeier-Types do we see today in comparison to then?

Of course it is related to strength only but it can be referenced to all sports where a lot of money and pressure for success is in the game...

Comment: So are you saying that, if a player never made it to the "top" of any league/team/public interest, they're likely to be natural? Because you can be on every drug in the world and still stuck at sports.

Comment: Being part of the top athletes takes more than just enhancement suplements, dedication, hard work and a lot more... is needed then just the required genetics. That is from my opinion where the most part is filtered out, the enhacement suplements are just the toping on the cake.

Comment: mmm....not really.

Comment: @johnP can you elaborate on mmm... not really? This is my experience, you are welcome to enlighten me with yours.